# Debugging Java Adapter in MobileFirst Fails in eclipse using java remote debugging cannot be done

Tags: java, eclipse, mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm developing JAVA adapters in MobileFirst. By MobileFirst tutorial in the [link](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/testing-and-debugging-adapters/), im trying to connect to my MF server from Eclipse under Run->Debug Configurations-> Remote Java Application. But it fails during connection and showing in the below error. Please clarify on this. Thanks.

Error : Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection timed out.
org.eclipse.jdi.TimeoutException

Comment: From the comments in that article you reference, have you checked the jvm.options for your server?

Comment: No, i've not checked that. How to do that?

Comment: Depends on your Java EE server. But see the comments about a JVM setting to enable remote debugging on a specific port: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/testing-and-debugging-adapters/#comment-3157644685